# JQuery find next DOM element by id where Id is not UNIQUE

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

This is doing my head in, I can't seem to find the dom element I need to find I have tried next/closest/find and just can't seem to the div.  The code is very self explanatory.

The line $(this).parent().siblings("div").find("#accounts").slideToggle(500); will not get me the div called accounts.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Households " class="householdRow">
    <div class="actions item"><img id="toggle" src="~/Images/toggle.png"/></div>
    <div class="item" data-bind="text: HouseholdId"></div>
    <div class="item" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    <div class="item">IACodes</div>
    <div class="item">Date</div>
    <div class="numberItem item">T12</div>
    <div class="numberItem item">AUA</div>
    <div class="item" data-bind="text: Segmentation.Name"></div>
    <div class="actions item"></div>
    <div id="accounts" data-bind="foreach: Accounts">
        <div class="accountRow">
            <div class="item" data-bind="text: xxx"></div>
            <div class="item" data-bind="text: xxx"></div>
            <div class="item" data-bind="text: xxx"></div>
            <div class="item" data-bind="dateFormat: xxx"></div>
            <div class="numberItem item" data-bind="text: xxx"></div>
            <div class="numberItem item" data-bind="text: xxx"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="actions item"><img id="delete" src="~/Images/delete.png"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    ...

    $(document).on("click", "#toggle", function () {
        //$(this).next("#accounts").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).parent().siblings("div").find("#accounts").slideToggle(500);
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: ID's need to be unique. Try changing `toggle` and `accounts` to classes instead.

Comment: you cant use .find with non-unique id's using the id selector. Try the attribute equals selector instead. Or better yet, don't use non-unique id's.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's must be unique or else you will get broken/undefined behavior when querying the DOM. Change `toggle` and `accounts` to classes instead.

Siblings() will return you a list of all siblings of the parent of `toggle`. Note that `accounts` is one of those siblings. When you call `find('.accounts')`, jQuery is looking for *descendants* of those siblings, so it will never find `accounts`. Instead, just use `accounts` as the filter in your `siblings()` call:

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".accounts").slideToggle(500);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adXhY/1)**

Answer (score 1):

While this could work you **really** should change your html to avoid duplicated ids as that's not valid and causes troubles when using id selectors as you already noticed

```
$(this).parent().siblings("div").find("[id=accounts]").slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('#accounts', $(this).parent().siblings("div"))`

Comment: Though, ideally you should change the output to use a *class* called 'accounts', and change the above `'#accounts'` to `'.accounts'`.

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong here:

```
$(this).parent().siblings("div").find("#accounts")
___________from_↑_____________________________to_↑
```

Here you are trying to find "accounts" DOM under the `$(this).parent().siblings("div")`, actually it can't find it.

So You can do it like this:

> $(this).parent().siblings("div#accounts").slideToggle(500);

or if you know the ID, you can directly code as:

> $("#accounts").slideToggle(500);

It is more effective.